# How to make the operation by hand into autorun script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7, autorun

I want to make the operation by hand into autorun script in win7.
My operation:
step1  To login into cmd console to run the command as administrator.

```
D:\wamp\wampmanager.exe
```

step2  To input timeout command in cmd console.

```
timeout  10
```

step3 To load data into my wordpress database

```
mysql -u root -ppasswd wpdatabase < e:/back.sql
```

Now i write the command as start.bat and save it in startup directory.

```
D:\wamp\wampmanager.exe
timeout  10
mysql -u root -ppasswd wpdatabase < e:/back.sql
```

It takes no effect.

The important thing is to make the start.bat run as administrator,how to run start.bat as administrator automatically at booting stage?How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vbscript that allows running right click commands on shell objects like files. Double click it for help.

> ---
>
> Windows Script Host
>
> ---
>
> **ShVerb**
>
> Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder
>
> `ShVerb <filename> [verb]`
>
> Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder
>
> The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator
>
> of the menu work when used this way
>
> The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running
>
> to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying
>
> a message box.
>
> ---
>
> OK
>
> ---

```
HelpMsg = vbcrlf & "  ShVerb" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  David Candy 2014" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf & "    ShVerb <filename> [verb]" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator" & vbcrlf & "  of the menu work when used this way" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf 
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running" & vbcrlf & "  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying" & vbcrlf & "  a message box." 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag = WScript.Arguments 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Ag.count = 0 then 
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - No file specified"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    Else If Ag.count = 1 then 
        If LCase(Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/")) = "/h" or Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/") = "/?" then 
            wscript.echo HelpMsg 
            wscript.quit
        End If
    ElseIf Ag.count > 2 then 
        wscript.echo vbcrlf & "  ShVerb - To many parameters" & vbcrlf & "  Use quotes around filenames and verbs containing spaces"  & vbcrlf
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    If fso.DriveExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
'       Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.self
        msgbox ag(0)
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    ElseIf fso.fileExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    Else
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - " & Ag(0) & " not found"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    Set objVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs

    'If only one argument list verbs for that item

    If Ag.count = 1 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If len(cmd) <> 0 then CmdList = CmdList & vbcrlf & replace(cmd.name, "&", "") 
        Next
        wscript.echo mid(CmdList, 2)

    'If two arguments do verbs for that item

    ElseIf Ag.count = 2 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If lcase(replace(cmd, "&", "")) = LCase(Ag(1)) then 
                wscript.echo(Cmd.doit)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    'Properties is special cased. Script has to stay running for Properties dialog to show.
        If Lcase(Ag(1)) = "properties" then
            WSHShell.AppActivate(ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties")
            msgbox "This message box has to stay open to keep the " & ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties dialog open."
        End If  
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Are ou saying that `d:\wamp...` causes the script to be run as administrator?

There are many, many articles already on SO which outline how to run a script as adminstrator.

Your problem may be that you are attempting to run `start.bat` - try renaming it to `startmysql.bat` since `start` is an internal `cmd` command.